# How can I use telugu font in beamer class?

Tags: beamer, fonts, polyglossia

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Beamer Presentation
% LaTeX Template
% Version 1.0 (10/11/12)
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% License:
% CC BY-NC-SA 3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/)
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   PACKAGES AND THEMES
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}

\mode<presentation> 
{

% The Beamer class comes with a number of default slide themes
% which change the colors and layouts of slides. Below this is a list
% of all the themes, uncomment each in turn to see what they look like.


\usetheme{Rochester}


% As well as themes, the Beamer class has a number of color themes
% for any slide theme. Uncomment each of these in turn to see how it
% changes the colors of your current slide theme.


\usecolortheme{wolverine}

%\setbeamertemplate{footline} % To remove the footer line in all slides uncomment this line
%\setbeamertemplate{footline}[page number] % To replace the footer line in all slides with a simple slide count uncomment this line

%\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{} % To remove the navigation symbols from the bottom of all slides uncomment this line
}

\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{telugu}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\telugufont{Lohit-Telugu.ttf}
%\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
%\newfontfamily{\cyrillicfonttt}{Liberation Mono}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   TITLE PAGE
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\title[NERC for Telugu]{Named Entity Recognition and Classification for Telugu} % The short title appears at the bottom of every slide, the full title is only on the title page

\author{SaiKiranmai G\\ 2012PHXF0531H} % Your name
%\institute[UCLA] % Your institution as it will appear on the bottom of every slide, may be shorthand to save space
%{
%University of California \\ % Your institution for the title page
%\medskip
%\textit{john@smith.com} % Your email address
%}

%\date{\today} % Date, can be changed to a custom date

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Important Dates} % Table of contents slide, comment this block out to remove it
%\tableofcontents % Throughout your presentation, if you choose to use \section{} and \subsection{} commands, these will automatically be printed on this slide as an overview of your presentation
\begin{itemize}
    \item Date of Qualifying Examination  : August 2013
    \item Research Proposal Submitted on : October 2013
    \item Research Proposal Accepted on   : November 2013
    \newline
    \item Supervisor: Prof. Aruna Malapati
    \item Co-Supervisor : Prof. N.L Bhanu Murthy
    \newline
     \item DAC Members :
     \begin{itemize}
        \item Prof. Chittaranjan Hota
        \item Prof. Tathagata Ray
     \end{itemize}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

%
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Workdone till now}

 \selectlanguage{telugu}ఢిల్లీలో \selectlanguage{english}DhillI.

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

error:

```
Package polyglossia Error: The current roman font does not contain the Telugu(polyglossia) Please define \telugufont with \newfontfamily. \select@language {telugu}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you switch to the `serif` font theme your method to load the font works:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{telugu}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\telugufont{Lohit-Telugu.ttf}




\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\otherlanguage{english}{Workdone till now}}

\selectlanguage{telugu}ఢిల్లీలో \selectlanguage{english}DhillI.

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]

If  you prefer sans serif font, you should define the `\telugufontsf` instead:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}

%\usefonttheme{serif}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\setmainlanguage{telugu}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\telugufont{Lohit-Telugu.ttf}
\newfontfamily\telugufontsf{Lohit-Telugu.ttf}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{\otherlanguage{english}{Workdone till now}}

\selectlanguage{telugu}ఢిల్లీలో \selectlanguage{english}DhillI.

\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]